# Restrict tastypie API to my app

Tags: ios, django, tastypie

i have a question about tastypie.
I have created a API using tastypie. Through this API i use
an app i have created to get information. I do no need to be authenticated, but i can.
So if i have signed in or not and open the url (Example: /api/posts/) through the app
all the posts are return.
So far so good :)

Is there any way to restrict the API to my APP? Using a key or something like that?
So that if i go in my browser to /api/posts/,
i will not be able to see the content?

I'm thinking about solving this using just POST, but is there any other way?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just implement your own `Authentication` object for your Resources to use. They've got an example of this at the [bottom of the doc page on tastypie authentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization).

Of course, it depends on how much "protection" you're looking for. By using a custom authenticator you could check for certain request headers, a certain user-agent, or similar - but none of these will stop anyone with 2 minutes and a packet sniffer.